# silverlight dataform control unavailable

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have RIA services installed and also have silverlight 3.0 but there is no system.windows.controls.data.dataform . On account of this, I am unable to use dataform control . WHat should I do?I have also tried to download the same but unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

DataForm is not currently in the SDK. Its found in the Toolkit.  Download and install the [Nov09 Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/36060) for Silverlight 3.

You need to add the `System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit` reference to your project.  Then the `DataForm` will be available in the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace.